# Interpreting phase-plane portraits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have found the phase plane for a "predator-prey model" system of differential equations:
$$\dot{x}=x^2-x^3-xy \qquad \dot{y}=yx-ya$$
where $x$ represents the population of prey and $y$ represents the population of predator. I want to interpret this for $a \geq 1$. It looks like this (I have used $a=1.1$):

[image: phase plane portrait]

I have used the Jacobian and nullclines to find equilibrium points at $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(a,a-a^2)$ and found that when $a\geq 1$, 
$(0,0)$ is a saddle (one eigenvalue is 0, the other is negative) - (although pplane didn't seem to recognise this as a stable point, any ideas why?),
 
$(1,0)$ is a stable sink (both eigenvalues are negative), and 
$(a,a-a^2)$ is a saddle (the eigenvalues are $\frac{a-2a^2\pm a \sqrt{4a^2-3}}{2}$ so the $\frac{a-2a^2- a \sqrt{4a^2-3}}{2}$ is negative and $\frac{a-2a^2+ a \sqrt{4a^2-3}}{2}$ is positive at a=1.1)

I want to use this portrait to show that the predators go extinct. How to I interpret this output this way?

Comment: If you're using the figure, start from a point in the first quadrant and follow the slope field.

Comment: As for your eigenvalue analysis, you've shown that the only stable equilibrium is the equilibrium where the predators are extinct. So now you only really need to rule out the possibility of a periodic orbit (which in general can't be done with just eigenvalues, as I recall; the van der Pol oscillator is the usual example). Sorry that I'm a bit rusty, I haven't tangled with this material for about 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

The positive quadrant is stable by the dynamics hence the only relevant equilibrium points are $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$. After that, start from $(x(0),y(0))$ with $x(0)\gt0$ and $y(0)\gt0$ and **follow the arrows**...

Since $x'\lt0$ when $x\gt1$, $x\leqslant1$ eventually, then $y'\leqslant-(a-1)y$ hence $y\to0$ and, since $(0,0)$ is a saddle point only reachable through the line $x=0$ and $x(t)\gt0$ for every $t$, $(x(t),y(t))\to(1,0)$.

[image]